# allow file_get_contents() / curl() from specified domains only

Tags: php

I'm building a script that uses file_get_contents to grab data from my website, which will be distributed among my clients. I don't want everyone to be able to grab this data, and therefore I would like the page with the data to be protected, so that only file_get_contents requests from specific domains are allowed.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTP authentication and/or IP-based restrictions.

The former is best done via your webserver config (e.g. .htaccess in case of apache), the latter can be done by checking if `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is in your whitelist.